# how to implement an ebook reader, which shows 2 pages of ebook on the window

Tags: ios, webview, epub

I have to develop an ebook reader app for iOS, which will show 2 pages of ebook at a time in the window.
what approach should I take for showing the 2 pages at a time IN CONTINUATION (the web view has to be continuous) ?

Comment: This has been discussed on here before. I think the most common approach is a `UIWebView`. Use HTML for content and CSS to style it.

Comment: i have done it with a single web view...but it doesn't give me a 2 page view....ny ideas how to implement that...am pretty new..

Comment: If someone has any sort of doubt in ebook iOS reader, you can post the problem straight here and i will try to help as much as i can as i have recently acquired quite a lot of information in the area...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was to modify the css property which fixes the size of the content displayed in `UIWebView`, then reduce it by half

```
NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding: 0px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; -webkit-column-width: %fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height, webView.frame.size.width/2];
```

Comment: above given solution is effective. So if by any chance its not working for you then comment here with your problem. You must be missing something else.